# relationship exists between entity list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Relationship between two users can be found out using below query.

```
RETURN EXISTS( (:User{_id:'User/123'})-[:Link]-(:User{_id:'User/567'}) )
```

What if it needs to be run for the list of queries like for below query i want to check if relationship exists

```
MATCH p=(u:User{_id:'User/8199'})-[r:Link]-(u1:User)
WHERE u1._id in ['12317291','User/09563','User/392942','User/24974','User/720']
RETURN p
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match the first use and then iterate through the lest and test for existence for each other user in the list.

```
MATCH (u:User {_id: 'User/8199'})
WITH u
UNWIND ['12317291','User/09563','User/392942','User/24974','User/720'] | u1] AS other_user
RETURN other_user, exists((u)-[:Link]->(:Test {name: other_user}))
```

Or you could do something like this if you wanted the actual users matched afterwards. Match the first user, test for a realtioship to a list of users and return a collection of matches.

```
MATCH (u:User {_id: 'User/8199'})
RETURN [(u)-[:Link]->(u1:User) 
  WHERE u1._id IN
  ['12317291','User/09563','User/392942','User/24974','User/720'] | u1] AS matches
```